# Teradata SQL Cast decimal to bigint

Tags: sql, casting, teradata

I am trying to run a select statement with 3 inner joins. The last join is a decimal to bigint conversion. I am trying to cast the decimal to bigint; however, I am still getting this error:

**Error during Prepare
S1000(-3754)[Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver]Teradata DatabasePrecision error in FLOAT type constant or during implicit conversions. (0.29 secs)**

Here is my query. I cannot understand what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help?

```
Select 
acct,
tramt,
TRINITDT,
trprocdt,
TRAN_CD,
TDDESC_1,
TDDESC_2,
MICM_TRAN_DESC,
LDGR_TYP_CD
from deposit.F_HRC_DPS_ACCT_TRAN_EOM as T

INNER JOIN customer.Cust_ACCT CA ON T.acct = CA.acct_NB 
inner join customer.CUST_IP_X_AR cipx on ca.cust_ar_id = cipx.cust_ar_id
inner join customer.cust c on Cast(cipx.cust_ip_id as bigint) = c.cust_ip_id
where Cast(cipx.cust_ip_id as int) in
(select top 50 Cast(cipx.cust_ip_id as bigint) from customer.cust)
```

update: I changed the inner join to this. Still same error.

```
INNER JOIN customer.Cust_ACCT CA ON T.acct = CA.acct_NB 
inner join customer.CUST_IP_X_AR cipx on ca.cust_ar_id = cipx.cust_ar_id
inner join customer.cust c on CAST(CAST(cipx.cust_ip_id AS numeric (27,0)) AS bigint)= c.cust_ip_id
where CAST(CAST(cipx.cust_ip_id AS numeric (27,0)) AS bigint) in
(select top 50 CAST(CAST(cipx.cust_ip_id AS numeric (27,0)) AS bigint) from customer.cust)
```

Comment: What are your actual data types in the join?  It sounds to me like `c.cust_ip_id` is  char or varchar. I think Teradata will implicitly cast that to a float when comparing to a numeric column.

Comment: c.cust_ip_id is a bigint according to the documentation.  Whereas cipx.cust_ip_id is a decimal.

Comment: I would guess that in one of your joins you are comparing a string type column to a numeric column.  Strip your query down to just the first join, see if it works, add one join at a time until the error occurs.

Comment: Somewhere there is a comparison between numeric and character, in which case both fields are implicitly CAST to FLOAT. Look at the EXPLAIN to see where `(FLOAT)` is being applied.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you! I found a int to varchar cast I was missing in the first join. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `CAST(CAST(column AS numeric (27,0)) AS bigint)`.

```
Select 
acct,
tramt,
TRINITDT,
trprocdt,
TRAN_CD,
TDDESC_1,
TDDESC_2,
MICM_TRAN_DESC,
LDGR_TYP_CD
from deposit.F_HRC_DPS_ACCT_TRAN_EOM as T

INNER JOIN customer.Cust_ACCT CA ON T.acct = CA.acct_NB 
inner join customer.CUST_IP_X_AR cipx on ca.cust_ar_id = cipx.cust_ar_id
inner join customer.cust c on CAST(CAST(cipx.cust_ip_id AS numeric(27,0)) AS bigint) = c.cust_ip_id
where CAST(CAST(cipx.cust_ip_id AS numeric(27,0)) AS bigint) in
(select top 50 CAST(CAST(cipx.cust_ip_id AS numeric(27,0)) AS bigint) from customer.cust)
```

Comment: I changed the inner join to this. Still same error. 'INNER JOIN customer.Cust_ACCT CA ON T.acct = CA.acct_NB 
inner join customer.CUST_IP_X_AR cipx on ca.cust_ar_id = cipx.cust_ar_id
inner join customer.cust c on CAST(CAST(cipx.cust_ip_id AS numeric (27,0)) AS bigint)= c.cust_ip_id
where CAST(CAST(cipx.cust_ip_id AS numeric (27,0)) AS bigint) in
(select top 50 CAST(CAST(cipx.cust_ip_id AS numeric (27,0)) AS bigint) from customer.cust)'